# CloudWatch Alarm Billing

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am having problems in identifying the CloudWatch bill. I do not have any active alarm (checking the alarms I have - 4 INSUFFICIENT DATA and 1 OK I can see in the history that none of them are current) but I still being charge for alarms.

The alarms in state INSUFFICIENT DATA are from DynamoDB tables (write and read capacity units limit). The alarm in state OK is an alarm that checks the billing so that is not greater than X.

I am treating missing data as ignore so the alarms do not get active if there is missing data (I recently changed this to get to the reason why I am being charged).

Am I being charge for any of these alarms? Maybe the Monthly Billing even though in its History does not show anything that suggest this?

I have checked the documentation but I do not get clearly the reason.

As far as I can see I do not have any Regular Alarm to be charged for.

I have been told that I am being charged because of the "AlarmMonitorUsage" but I cannot find where that is and how to turn it off.

[image: CloudWatch Billing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anybody else has this problem I post the answer:

I was told that the alarm that was causing the charges was AlarmMonitorUsage.

Checking the report that can be exported from Amazon, I can see the alarms in it (AlarmMonitorUsage apart from others). If I sum up the UsageValue for those alarms I get 9986.33. AWS has 10 free alarms included in the free tier which are being calculated per hour.

9986.33 alarms/(30 days * 24 hours) = 13.869902777777778.

13.869902777777778 - 10 (free alarms) = 3.869902777777778.

Those 3.8 alarms are the ones that I am being charged for.

Comment: Reports in CSV can be obtained from [Download Usage Report](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/reports/usage)